# Solr - ranking documents based on term order

Tags: sorting, solr, ranking

Suppose I have a multivalue field "category" and two documents:

doc1: category=[A,B]
doc2: category=[B,A]

A document may belong to more than category, and the categories are listed in the order of their relevance. So, when searching for "category:A" I want doc1 sorted before doc2. This means I have to sort by a function that takes term's order of appearance into account. Is this possible?

Comment: How many categories are we talking about as a maximum? If the number is low, using a separate field for each category for sorting could be an option (.. or good enough with just the two first categories).

Comment: There are 6 categories at most, so this is certainly an option. I'd prefer a more elegant (and general) solution, but if one doesn't exist, this will be my fallback.